# css menu moving when bold

Tags: xhtml, menu, dotnetnuke, css

I have a menu which looks like this:

[image]

When the user clicks on Recruitment, it goes bold (as it should do) but moves the whole menu 1 or 2px to the left. I am using DNNnav.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant css?

Comment: Can you code it up in jsfiddle please.

Comment: please, can you fill a fiddle with markup and css code of your menu?

Comment: And if all else fails, you can always give the text `color:#000` instead of making it bold.

Comment: I cant really show you as its a DNN nav.. Its hard to reproduce in jsfiddle

Comment: here is my jsfiddle but i can recreate the problem in there. - http://jsfiddle.net/zvZ5p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boldness of fonts uses extra space. If you make sure that every menu-point has a set width with for example `width: 100px;`, it should not jump place when you hover over it, as it will be a steady 100px, no matter what's inside.

Good luck!

P.S. If needed you should of course maker it wider than 100px.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Its almost as if i need the menu items to be fluid width. How can i do this?

Comment: Make the width in percentages (100%) instead of px (100px), but I don't think that will fix the jumping problem.

Comment: I looked at it, but the menu items don't go bold when I hover over them.

Comment: Thats because its injecting jquery to make it bold on selected. I cant really recreate this as its all done from a CMS

Comment: Why are you using Jquery to make it bold when selected? It's so easy with some CSS trickery. http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200503/setting_the_current_menu_state_with_css/ for example

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to go through your coded in jsFiddles. But just try to give a fix width in px for your 'span.txt' `span.txt{ width:100px;}` or maybe min-width `span.txt{ min-width:100px;}` may help.